# How to set a breakpoint programmatically via a chrome extension.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript-debugger

I am trying to set a breakpoint  in a JavaScript file of a webpage using a chrome extension.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.debugger.attach({"tabId" : tab.id }}, "1.0");
   chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
        "tabId": tab.id},
    "Debugger.setBreakpoint",
            {
                "Location": {"lineNumber": 12},
            },
    function(response) {
          chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
});

var version = "1.0";
```